# __tests__/App-test.js ● Test suite failed to run

Tags: react-native, jestjs

FAIL  **tests**/App-test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.



  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
  at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:37:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-file-viewer/index.js:4:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/screens/CreatePostScreen.js:8300:51)
```

Comment: can you please share your code or some config file

Comment: Pulkit Aggarwal Thanks a lot. The problem is solved

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: jest-setup file issue! some config are missing